# How i can get the data from CMD console nodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I can get data from cmd console in node.js using `process.stdout` to ask for data and `process.stdin` for getting the answer.

It is good, but how i can get the current text that the user is typing? like `onkeypress` event, and also without asking the user anything. If not that every time the user types something, I can get it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use module like ioHook https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook